# how to do responsive images and blocks with bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How to do responsive product images in bootstrap? I need all the columns and images scale down when i'm sizing the browser like here: [link](http://styleart.com/All-designs/?gendertype=man)

```
<div id="product-list">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-15 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 item">
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/220x322" width="220" height="322" class="img-responsive" alt="Simple product">
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <div class="product-name">Rick Owens</div>
                        <div class="product-model">Glass ice nappa leather bomber</div>
                        <div class="product-price">€ 1161.00</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- more products -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the html [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ejn31n1/)

Comment: Did you checked the documentation given by the bootstrap ? It seems that you are not familiar with the bootstrap classes properly.. Check out the documentation here: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: yes i read, i need 5 columns firstly, so i write own col 15 class, but next classes are default by bootstrap

Comment: I don't understand why did you made `col-15` class ?? Can you please elaborate on this ?

Comment: because bootstrap have not default class with 5 columns and 20%

Comment: There is no need of doing like that.. Bootstrap will handle all things for you. You just need to call the correct classes and you are done. That's it.

Comment: can help and write structure how to name class with 20 % and 5 columns

Comment: Study this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your images the 'img-responsive' class and wrap it in the default bootstrap tree (container - row - col)

Answer (score 0):

Adding Bootstrap's built in .img-responsive class to any image tag will do the job.

The .img-responsive class applies the following CSS properties to the image:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
```